# Why does my SVG measure at double the size, double the width and height?

Tags: svg

I have tested this in NW.JS v0.21.1 (chromium 57.0.2987.98), in Safari 10, and in Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit).  My simple SVG measures at 64px width and height, but it is specified as 32px width and height.  There is no scaling going on. I checked to make sure the browser zoom level was reset.  When I measure the pixels of this svg in Photoshop, it shows it at 64px.  How can I get precise measurements?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
    width="32" 
    height="32" 
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <path d="M 25,25, 75,25 50,75 z" style="stroke-width: 2; stroke: red;"></path>
</svg>
```

Here is a screenshot below.  Please note that it may look expanded on this web page.  By right clicking and downloading it, you can see that the 32px SVG is showing up as a 64px image when rendered.
[image: Test.svg]

Comment: I have tried it with px and without it.  It still shows up as a 64px image.  Thank you though.

Comment: Retina display maybe? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Paul LeBeau... You hit the nail on the head.  I have a Mac Retina display.  I checked it against other image sizes.  That's what it is.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots